# Finding the area of a triangle in a trapezoid and the area of the trapezoid based on the given information.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, triangles, pythagorean-triples

An isosceles trapezoid $ABCD$ has bases $AD = 17$cm, $BC = 5$cm, and leg $AB = 10 $cm. A line is drawn through vertex $B$ so that it bisects diagonal $AC$ and intersect $AD$ at point $M$.

1) Find the area of $ΔBDM$.

2) What is the area of $ABCD$?

Image 1: (For the area of ΔBDM)
[image]
Image 2 : (For the area of the whole figure)
[image]

What I did:

So I didn't know what to do for the first question so I skipped it. **Any help would be appreciated.**

The second one was easy because the height makes a right triangle and we can see that the right triangle has a $6-8-10 (3-4-5)$ Pythagorean triple. So from there, the height is 8. I can plug all of this information into the formula for the area of a trapezoid: $0.5*(b1+b2)*h$. I finally get the area of the trapezoid as 88 cm^2.

**So I don't know how to do the first question (the area of the    triangle) so any help would be appreciated.**

Sorry for the crude drawings.

Comment: You draw AC as it is angle bisector. Is it?

Comment: Sorry I assumed that when I wrote the question. I will remove that.

Comment: If you re-drew your drawings on gridded paper, whenever you determine each new detail, you would have ended up with [this image](http://nominal-animal.net/answers/quad.svg), and found the problem easy to solve.

Comment: Yes, that drawing on the grid paper is much accurate. My trapezoid is not accurately drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: let $AC$ and $BM$ intersect at $P$, then $\Delta BCP$ is equal to $\Delta AMP$.

Comment: Ok, even though there are two congruent right triangles, how would this help because we are looking for the the area of ΔBDM not the area of ΔABM?

Comment: ΔBDM only has a small part of ΔBPC in it.

Comment: Further hints: Can you find $AM$? Can you find $MD$? How do you find the area of $\Delta BMD$?

Comment: Ah, ok I can see the length of MD is 17-5=12 because the two right triangles are congruent. Because we already know that the height is 8, we can find the area of  ΔBMD.

Comment: ΔBMD is 0.5*(height*base) = 0.5*(8*12) = 0.5*(96) = **48**

Comment: You got it, good luck.

Comment: So would **48** be correct

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Put whole thing in coordinate system so that $A(-{17\over 2},0)$, $D({17\over 2},0)$, $B(-{5\over 2},8)$ and $C({5\over 2},8)$. Then midpoint of $AC$ is $R(-3,4)$ and a line $BR$ has equation $$ y= 8x+28$$

This line cuts x-axis at $M(-{7\over 2},0)$, so $DM= 12$ and $$Area (BMD) ={8\cdot 12\over 2}=48$$

Comment: That another great way to find the answer to the question too.